# How to print Line numbers as and when java code is executed

Tags: java, code-coverage

H All,
I want to trace which lines are executed in my code so that I can highlight those lines. Due to this i am able to trace the code which is not tested.

i found out that JDB is way through which I can actually debug my application but I am not able to connect JDB with my eclipse code which is running. So in good scenario what I want is my code is running on eclipse and I am connected to that code via JDB and able to get all the line numbers which are executred

Comment: You know tools like [Emma](http://www.eclemma.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the line number in the file that the stack trace code is called in:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();
```

This will get you the line number in the file where the method that contains the stack trace code is called:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Eclipse Debugger would do the job, so you can go trough you code line by line

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junor

but this is included in nearly any ide

Comment: I think about using this. However consider case that I have 1000 lines of code so after every line I do have to call new Throwable().printStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber() something to get the line number which is not correct solution i think . Any other better way to do this. with JDB it is possible but I am not able to link my JAVA code which is in eclipse with JDB which I am running via command prompt.

Comment: I dont want to use eclipse debugger because I want to create my own utility tool to observe that what percentage of my code is covered while testing .

Comment: Did you tested earlier? It's recommended to test new classes or modules after they're finished and not only at the end. (When it's possible)

Comment: Yes I am trying to attach this utility/ tool along with testing through which I can actually test the code and get the code coverage happening because fo testing